# Mapping data from array in child component and parent component

Tags: javascript, arrays, reactjs

I have data stored in data.js file in array. I am showing that data in Child component (only the first object in array). I want to map through same array in parent component (by rendering `<ChildComponent>`). How can I do that?

data.js

```
export default {
  accordionItems: [
    {
      id: 1,
      title: 'Why is my car not green?',
      answer: 'We ran out of green color',
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      title: 'Where have all the drivers gone?',
      answer: 'It\'s lunch time',
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      title: 'Do you have a book of complains',
      answer: 'You can write at info@mail.eu',
    },
  ],
};
```

child component

```
import Data from './data';

class AccordionItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      question: Data.accordionItems[0], //if I remove [0], no data is rendered
    };
  }

 return (
    <div >
      <div>
        <p>{question.title}</p>
        <button>toggle</button>
      </div>
      <p>{question.answer}</p>
      <hr />
    </div>
 );
```

Parent Component

```
import AccordionItem from './AccordionItem';
import Data from './data';


class Accordion extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      accordionItems: Data.accordionItems,
    };
  }
render() {
    const { accordionItems } = this.state;
    return accordionItems.map(accordionItem => (
      <AccordionItem key={accordionItem.id} />
```

I want to get all 3 objects from 'data' array in Parent component, now I am getting 3 same components with just first object.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass the item down as props:

```
 <AccordionItem question={accordionItem} ... />
```

The  you can access it in the render() method:

```
render() {
 const { question } = this.props;

 return (
   <div >
     <div>
       <p>{question.title}</p>
       <button>toggle</button>
     </div>
     <p>{question.answer}</p>
   </div>
 );
}
```

You shouldn't use the state at all (yet).

Answer (score 2):

You can simply pass data from map function itself like:

```
accordionItems.map(accordionItem => (
      <AccordionItem
        key={accordionItem.id}
        open={[`isOpen-${accordionItems.id}`]}
        data={accordionItem}
      />
));
```

And in the Child:

```
class AccordionItem extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      question: props.data, //data from map function in parent
    };
  }
```

Comment: This seems to work for Parent component. but child component throws an error: Cannot read property 'title' of undefined

Comment: In single item i needed to pass index of array. ```<AccordionItem data={Data.accordionItems[0]}``` It is ok.

Comment: Here is the best possible solution according to me : https://codesandbox.io/s/y2lrywpk21

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should read a bit more about [components and passing props](https://reactjs.org/docs/components-and-props.html) in React.

What you could do to make this work is instead of importing `Data` in your `AccordionItem` component, you pass it down to the `AccordionItem` via props.

This would look something like this:

```
import AccordionItem from './AccordionItem';
import Data from './data';


class Accordion extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      accordionItems: Data.accordionItems,
    };
  }

  render() {
    const { accordionItems } = this.state;
    return accordionItems.map(accordionItem => (
        <AccordionItem
          key={accordionItem.id}
          item={accordionItem}
          open={[`isOpen-${accordionItems.id}`]}
        />
    ))
  }
```

Now the item should become accessible via props in the child component:

```
 class AccordionItem extends Component {

   render(){
     const { question } = this.props
     return (
       <div >
         <div>
           <p>{question.title}</p>
           <button>toggle</button>
         </div>
         <p>{question.answer}</p>
         <hr />
       </div>
     );
   }
```